# Удаление лишних символов из строки

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как из строки вида `/Date(1245398693390)/`. получить `1245398693390`?

Comment: Каким способом удалять-то?? Просто вырезать все цифры или именно по шаблону?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"/Date(1245398693390)/".match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"/Date(1245398693390)/".replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

В текущей формулировке регулярные выражения не нужны.

```
'/Date(1245398693390)/'.slice(6, -2)
```